# Graphing elliptical curves based on group operation

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I just found [this](https://cp4space.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/elliptic-curve-calculator/) and it blew my mind (he gives an elliptical curve to do multiplication). If I understand correctly (from reading the link and other things) the Abelian group he is using is $\mathbb{R}^*/\{10^n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ under multiplication of coset representatives. I want to graph these using my computer. I am very willing to do all the programming my self but I don't know how he does this. He says that he used ["a transcendental function related to the Weierstrass P-function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) and he expounds as to the general well known techniques he used to approximate this function. That's all fine and good but he didn't really go much further into this.

To be more precise I want to do the following.

Given a group operation on the reals $* : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ compute the constants $a, b$ in elliptical curve $y^2 = x^3 + a \cdot x + b$ corresponding to the group $\mathbb{R}^*/\{10^n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ with group operation $(x H) *' (y H) = (x*y H)$.

Now of course approximation will be used but I think that I am familiar enough with numerical methods to be able to approximate about what ever I need (or I can ask a different question if I can't figure that out). What I do not know is the math behind finding those constants

So basically what is the math behind finding those constants?

edit: As pointed out $\mathbb{R}/10\mathbb{R}$ makes no sense because $\mathbb{R} = 10\mathbb{R}$. I'm sure this is a factor group because I can tell you what the cosets look like $\{x \cdot 10^n\ | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ but I can't seem to figure out a better way to express this. I.E. 10 and 1 are in the same coset so the should be represented by the same point on the elliptical curve.

edit2: I think I got it. I just had to specify the coset in an unnatural way.

Comment: $10\mathbb R=\mathbb R$

Comment: Right, that works with integers not rationals and reals. Let's see. What is a way to express that multiplying or dividing by 10 is the identity function in this group? Mod 10? is that $\mathbb{R}_{10}$?

Comment: Probably $\mathbb{R}/10\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: No that isn't right either. 1, and 10 should be in the same group but 20 should not be in that group. in $\mathbb{R}/10\mathbb{Z}$ the identity contains both 10 and 20 but in the group I am looking for (that I misdenoted clearly) should have 1, 10, 1/10, 100, 1/100, etc.. in the identity.

Comment: Yea so mod is not what I meant at all. the cosets contain different factors of the powers of 10.

Comment: In this quotient group two real numbers are in the same coset iff you get one from the other by moving the decimal point. So for example $70.2$, $7.02$ and $0.0000702$ are in the same coset. Each coset has a unique representative in the interval $[1,10)$ (include $(-10,-1]$ if negative numbers are allowed). Zero must be left out, as the group operation must be multiplication. The subgroup of positive numbers is isomorphic to the additive group $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$. Logarithm in base 10 is the isomorphism.